# Jquery 1.8, checking if the item is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` element `<div id='someId' style="visibility: hidden;"></div>`

$(#someId).css('visibility'); // returns "hidden"
$(#someId).is(':hidden'); // returns false
$(#someId).is(':visible'); // returns true

Is this a bug in JQuery 1.8 or I didn't figure out something ?

Comment: :hidden refers to the display attribute I believe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:hidden` selector can refers to :

- `display: none`
- `type="hidden"`
- `width: 0px; height: 0px`
- An ancestor element is hidden.

So `visibility: hidden` doesn't enter in those cases.

See jQuery doc here : http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

**EDIT**

To check `visibility` property :

```
if($("#someId").css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
   /* some code */
}
```

Comment: Simply : `if($("#someId").css('visibility') == 'hidden') {}`

Comment: ok, as I see beside explicit checking there's nothing to do, thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Please refer the following jquery links :

[:hidden Selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/)

[:visible Selector](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Here reason is clearly mentioned that **Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout**

Answer (score 1):

From jquery.com:

```
Elements can be considered hidden for several reasons:

They have a CSS display value of none.
They are form elements with type="hidden".
Their width and height are explicitly set to 0.
An ancestor element is hidden, so the element is not shown on the page.
```

Answer (score 0):

is(':visible') and is('hidden') takes the display Property as reference